# Showing $-\pi n \int_0^1 e^x \cos(\pi n x)\ dx = -\pi n \frac{e^1 (-1)^n -1}{1+n^2\pi^2}$

Tags: analysis

J'aimerai trouver que
$$-\pi n \int_0^1 e^x \cos(\pi n x)\ dx = -\pi n \frac{e^1 (-1)^n -1}{1+n^2\pi^2}$$

J'ai essayé avec un changement de variables $u=exp(x)$, mais je trouve que l'intégrale est nulle.

Translation:

> I would like to find
> $$-\pi n \int_0^1 e^x \cos(\pi n x)\ dx = -\pi n \frac{e^1 (-1)^n -1}{1+n^2\pi^2}$$

I tried with a change of variables $u = exp (x)$, but I found the integral to be zero.

Comment: Voulez-vous une réponse en français ou en anglais fera l'affaire

Comment: Astuce : Essayez l'intégration par parties

Comment: Peu importe la langue, même si je suis français

Comment: Olivier, en réalité cette intégrale provient déjà d'une intégration par parties

Comment: Oui Anitej, c'est la réponse que je veux obtenir

Comment: @Romain44 Alright, I'll type out all my working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, we have to make use of the [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) formula.

The integration by parts formula is as follows:

> $$\int_a^b u(x)v'(x)dx = \biggl[u(x)v(x)\biggr]_a^b - \int_a^b u'(x)v(x)dx$$

Before we start using this formula, let us define our starting integral (the reason why we do this will become more apparent later on in this solution).

$$\text {Let } I = -\pi n\int_0^1e^xcos(\pi nx)dx$$

Let us now define our individual functions (it does not matter which function is which, they are interchangeable).

> $\text {Let } v(x) = e^x.$
> $\therefore v'(x) = e^x$
>
> $\text {Let } u(x) = cos(\pi nx).$
> $\therefore u'(x) = -\pi nsin(\pi nx)$

Let us now make use of the integration by parts formula.

> $$I = -\pi n \Biggl[\biggl[e^x cos(\pi nx)\biggr]_0^1 + \int_0^1 e^x \pi nsin(\pi nx)dx\Biggr]$$
>  $$I = -\pi n \Biggl[\biggl[e^1 cos(\pi n)\biggr] - \biggl[e^0 cos(0)\biggr] + \pi n\int_0^1 e^x sin(\pi nx)dx\Biggr]$$
>  $$I = -\pi n \Biggl[ecos(\pi n) - 1 + \pi n\int_0^1 e^x sin(\pi nx)dx\Biggr]$$
>  $$I = -e\pi ncos(\pi n) + \pi n - \pi^2 n^2\int_0^1 e^x sin(\pi nx)dx$$

We can now use the integration by parts formula once again by redefining our functions.

> $\text {Let } v(x) = e^x.$
> $\therefore v'(x) = e^x$
>
> $\text {Let } u(x) = sin(\pi nx).$
> $\therefore u'(x) = \pi ncos(\pi nx)$

Thus, the integral can be evaluated as follows:

> $$I = -e\pi ncos(\pi n) + \pi n - \pi^2 n^2\Biggl[\biggl[e^xsin(\pi nx)\biggr]_0^1 - \int_0^1 e^x \pi n cos(\pi nx)dx\Biggr]$$
>  $$I = -e\pi ncos(\pi n) + \pi n - \pi^2 n^2\Biggl[\biggl[e^1sin(\pi n)\biggr] - \biggl[e^0sin(0)\biggr] - \pi n\int_0^1 e^x cos(\pi nx)dx\Biggr]$$
>  $$I = -e\pi ncos(\pi n) + \pi n - \pi^2 n^2\Biggl[esin(\pi n) - \pi n\int_0^1 e^x cos(\pi nx)dx\Biggr]$$
>  $$I = -e\pi ncos(\pi n) + \pi n - e\pi^2 n^2sin(\pi n) + \pi^3 n^3\int_0^1 e^x cos(\pi nx)dx$$

Note that we can now redefine the last integral as follows:

> $$\pi^3 n^3\int_0^1 e^x cos(\pi nx)dx = -\pi^2 n^2 \Bigg[-\pi n\int_0^1 e^x cos(\pi nx)dx\Bigg]$$
>  $$\text {Since } I = -\pi n\int_0^1e^xcos(\pi nx)dx \text {,}$$
>  $$\pi^3 n^3\int_0^1 e^x cos(\pi nx)dx = -I\pi^2 n^2$$

Thus, the integral now becomes an equation:

> $$I = -e\pi ncos(\pi n) + \pi n - e\pi^2 n^2sin(\pi n) - I\pi^2 n^2$$
>  $$I + I\pi^2 n^2= -e\pi ncos(\pi n) + \pi n - e\pi^2 n^2sin(\pi n)$$
>  $$I(1 + \pi^2 n^2) = -e\pi ncos(\pi n) + \pi n - e\pi^2 n^2sin(\pi n)$$
>  $$I = \frac {-e\pi ncos(\pi n) + \pi n - e\pi^2 n^2sin(\pi n)} {\pi^2 n^2 + 1}$$
>  $$I = -\frac {\pi n[e\pi nsin(\pi n) + ecos(\pi n) - 1]} {\pi^2 n^2 + 1}$$

$$\text {Since } I = -\pi n\int_0^1e^xcos(\pi nx)dx \text {,}$$

> $$-\pi n\int_0^1e^xcos(\pi nx)dx = -\frac {\pi n[e\pi nsin(\pi n) + ecos(\pi n) - 1]} {\pi^2 n^2 + 1}$$

---

I hope this helps! I'm still new to MSE, so I would really appreciate any and all feedback. Thank you!

Comment: Merci, j'ai compris Je ne pensais pas que ça aurait pu être si long

Comment: My pleasure, and thank you for the feedback. I try to set out my solution in as much detail as possible to avoid confusion, but I will try to limit the length of my solution from now on. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

$$S=-n\pi\int_{0}^{1} e^x  cos(n\pi x) dx =-n \pi ~\Re \int_{0}^{1} e^{(1+in \pi)x} dx=-n\pi~\Re\left(\frac{e^{(1+in\pi)}-1}{(1+in\pi)}\right)$$
$$S=-n\pi \frac{e(-1)^n-1}{1+n^2\pi^2}$$